UV cancellation in $S$, $T$, $U$ (oblique parameters) in unitary gauge in the SM
I am PhD student in particle physics and I am trying to compute the three oblique parameters in a BSM theory (a $\mathrm{SU}(5)$ theory with KK modes).
In order to check my calculation, I always verify if the UV and $\mu$-dependent part of my oblique parameters cancel well.
The thing is, since my theory is much bigger than the SM, I am doing the calculations in the unitary gauge with $\xi,\xi_Z$ going to infinity and $\xi_A$ to 1 in order to reduce the number of diagrams and not having to introduce FP ghosts.
I already did the calculations for the loops with fermions and everything work and now I am looking to compute the loops with everything else.
Before starting a too big calculation in my BSM theory, I am doing the calculation in the SM just to see how the UV cancellation happens.
I am using the book The Standard Model in the making by Bardin and Passarino. And the thing is that, when I use their results in the Feynman t'Hooft gauge, I get an UV cancellation for the $T$ parameters (the easiest to compute, I didn't check the others yet but I guess its the same), but when doing in the unitary gauge, their results don't cancel at all for the $T$ parameter. (And at a first glance it seems to not be the case either for my BSM theory in unitary gauge).
So my question is the following, do you know any books or articles explaining in details the computation of self energies of vector bosons in the unitary gauge? Because obviously there must something that I am missing but I don't know what it is. And if someone is familiar with that type of calculation I would be happy to talk about and go further in details but I didn't want to overload this post with equations.

Are the oblique parameters observable, and therefore gauge invariant? (I thought so?) If that's the case, then your unitary gauge calculation must be wrong if it disagrees with the Feynman-'t Hooft gauge calculation that you trust, right? I also thought it was very difficult to do loop calculations in unitary gauge due to the weird behavior of the propagators at high energies, although it's been a while since I've done stuff like this.

Hey thanks for the answer. Yes the oblique parameters are observables and thus finite and gauge invariante. The loops are not hard top calculate since all integrals are tabuled and you can use Package X to compute them automaticaly. I dont suspect my calculation in the SM to be wrong because I took it from the same book but I suspect missing a subtelty in the unitary gauge since I dont get a cancellation whereas I get it with the Feynman gauge.

I mean you made a mistake in the sense that you have done two calculations that must agree with each other but which are currently not agreeing. Although I appreciate what you are saying that you may have correctly computed all the diagrams you meant to compute but are missing some other diagrams, or something subtle like that, as opposed to a trivial calculation mistake. I hope someone here can give you more concrete advice.

I am wondering if the error does not come from the missing tadpoles in the WW and ZZ self energy. In Bardin Passarino they don't include them in the 't Hooft Feynman computations (and it works) but they sey that they are necessary to deal with the issue of gauge invariance. But they are very subtle to handle and it's not very well explained how these tadpole contributions are involved in self energy, unfortunately.
